# How to set the title of the paper to be placed at the bottom?

Tags: xetex, titles

In the Latex template I used, the new title had to be placed on the next page, and it was unwilling to be placed at the bottom, even if it was not the last line. Every time a blank is left. How do I set it up so that it can be placed at the bottom?
The font in the source code is Chinese.

```
    % Copyright (c) 2019 Bochen Tan
% Public domain.
%本模板的宗旨是尽量绿色，不需要附加安装任何东西。
%按照教务部下发的WORD说明文档格式，下简称“说明”
%没有封面和评阅表，这两部分请直接在Cover&ReviewTable.doc中写再输出pdf拼到一起
%doc小改动：封面校徽和文字替换为了高清版本，“题目：”和中文题目对齐，中英文题目分在了表的两行
%doc小改动：插入了两个白页，使得连续打印的时候封面和表格都在奇数页
%正文部分改动：在每一页下方中央加了页码，因为说明中页眉不分奇偶页，所以页码就都在中央吧
%不含自动的参考文献，因为说明中参考文献格式不典型，请手动输入或自行写程序
%在Windows或Linux下渲染出字体更接近说明，Mac OS上字体不太一样
%有警告\headheight is too small，fancyhdr的上距离有点小，似乎问题不大

\documentclass[UTF8,openany,AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant,cs4size]{ctexbook}
%openany 使一章可以从偶数页开始，因为说明中每一章并没有只能从奇数页开始，虽然这是常理
%AutoFakeBold 和 AutoFakeSlant 因为 CJK 里没有真正的加粗和倾斜，如果额外字体则效果更好
%cs4size 因为要求主题是小四号字

\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.18cm,right=3.18cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
%office中正常页边距



\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}



\usepackage{cite}
\newcommand{\upcite}[1]{\textsuperscript{\cite{#1}}} %引用在右上角



\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small,labelsep=space]{caption} %五号，宋体/Time new roman
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}} %表格和图片编号不分章节，直接1，2，3 ...
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}} %公式标签 章.公式（均为阿拉伯数字）



\usepackage{tocloft} %自定义目录，说明中没有明确规定，和WORD自动生成目录格式一致

%“全文目录”四个字的格式
\renewcommand\cftbeforetoctitleskip{0pt}
\renewcommand\cftaftertoctitleskip{0pt}
\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\bfseries\heiti\zihao{2}}

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\heiti\normalsize} %黑体小四
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep} %有点连到页码，点间距不确定，待改
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\songti\normalsize} %宋体小四页码
\renewcommand\cftbeforechapskip{0pt}

%1. 第一级 五号宋体，缩进两个字符，页码一致
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\songti\small}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\songti\small}
\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{.} %一级目录号后加点
\renewcommand\cftsecindent{2em}
\renewcommand\cftbeforesecskip{0pt}

%1.1 第二级 五号宋体，缩进四个字符，页码一致
\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{\songti\small}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpagefont{\songti\small}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecindent{4em}
\renewcommand\cftbeforesubsecskip{0pt}

%1.1.1 第二级 五号宋体，缩进四个字符，页码一致
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecfont{\songti\small}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecpagefont{\songti\small}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecindent{4em}
\renewcommand\cftbeforesubsubsecskip{0pt}



\usepackage{titlesec}%自定义章节标题
\CTEXsetup[format={\bfseries\center\heiti\zihao{2}},beforeskip=0pt]{chapter}
%第一章  绪论（二号、黑体） beforeskip为上方垂直距离看起来还比说明偏大，待改

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%使目录中有三级标题，即subsubsection

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} % 使得不显示章名，只显示节名
\titleformat{\section}
{\raggedright\zihao{3}\bfseries\songti}
{\thesection.\quad}
{0pt}
{}%1. 第一级（三号、宋体/Time new roman、加粗）

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\raggedright\bfseries\zihao{4}\songti}
{\thesubsection\quad}
{0pt}
{}%1.1 第二级（四号，宋体/Time new roman，加粗）

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\raggedright\bfseries\zihao{-4}\songti}
{\thesubsubsection\quad}
{0pt}
{}%1.1.1 第三级（小四，宋体/Time new roman，加粗）



%[Yujie]
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}


% 封面依赖的宏包
\input{CoverHead}
% 评阅表依赖的宏包
\input{ReviewTableHead}



\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

% 封面中需要修改的内容直接在此处更改即可
\newcommand{\chineseTitle}{中文题目（楷体，二号，加粗）}
\newcommand{\englishTitle}{英文题目（Times New Roman，三号，加粗）}
\newcommand{\name}{张三}
\newcommand{\studentID}{15000xxxxx}
\newcommand{\school}{信息科学技术学院}
\newcommand{\major}{电子信息科学与技术}
\newcommand{\advisor}{李四}
% 插入封面
\input{cover}
\clearpage

% 插入导师评阅表
% \input{ReviewTable}
% \clearpage


% \linespread{1.5}\selectfont
% \chapter*{版权声明}
% \setcounter{page}{0}
% % 本页不计页码
% \thispagestyle{empty}
% % 本页无页眉和页脚
% 任何收存和保管本论文各种版本的单位和个人，未经本论文作者同意，不得将本论文转借他人，亦不得随意复制、抄录、拍照或以任何方式传播。否则，引起有碍作者著作权之问题，将可能承担法律责任。
% \clearpage

% %版权声明后空白一页，使得摘要从奇数页开始。
% \quad
% \setcounter{page}{0}
% % 本页不计页码
% \thispagestyle{empty}
% % 本页无页眉和页脚
% \clearpage



\pagestyle{fancy}
\normalsize
\linespread{1.5}\selectfont
%小四号，宋体/Time new roman，1.5倍行距
\chapter*{摘要}
Copyright (c) 2019 Bochen Tan

Public domain.

本模板的宗旨是尽量绿色，不需要附加安装任何东西。

按照教务部下发的WORD说明文档格式，下简称“说明”

没有封面和评阅表，这两部分请直接在Cover\&ReviewTable.doc中写再输出pdf拼到一起

doc小改动：封面校徽和文字替换为了高清版本，“题目：”和中文题目对齐，中英文题目分在了表的两行

doc小改动：插入了两个白页，使得连续打印的时候封面和表格都在奇数页

正文部分改动：在每一页下方中央加了页码，因为说明中页眉不分奇偶页，所以页码就都在中央吧

不含自动的参考文献，说明中参考文献格式不典型，请手动输入或自行写程序

在Windows或Linux下渲染出字体更接近说明，Mac OS上字体不太一样

有警告$\backslash$ headheight is too small，fancyhdr的上距离有点小，似乎问题不大

\bigskip
\noindent{\bfseries\songti 关键词: }



\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{摘要} %手动加入目录
\fancypagestyle{plain} %因为latex默认每章第一页是plain所以需要重置一下plain和说明统一
{
    \fancyhf{} %清空

    \fancyhead[RE,RO]{摘要}
    %偶数页右页眉，奇数页右页眉均为“摘要”，及章名\leftmark

    \fancyhead[LE,LO]{MIPSR1000}
    %偶数页左页眉，奇数页左页眉均为“MIPSR1000”

    \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{~\thepage~}
    %偶数页和奇数页中页脚为页码，从对称考虑，因为每页在说明中都是一样的，不分奇偶

    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt} %页眉线宽度，可调，不太清楚说明中是多少，待改

    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} %页脚线宽度为0，既没有
}

%默认的风格是fancy，设置于下，用于每章非第一页
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{摘要}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{MIPSR1000}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{~\thepage~}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\clearpage






\small
\linespread{1.5}\selectfont
%5号，Time new roman，1.5倍行距
\chapter*{\bfseries Abstract}

\bigskip
\noindent
{\bfseries Key Words: }



\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bfseries Abstract} %Abstract加粗
\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RE,RO]{Abstract}
    \fancyhead[LE,LO]{MIPSR1000}
    \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{~\thepage~}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{Abstract}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{MIPSR1000}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{~\thepage~}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\clearpage





\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RE,RO]{全文目录}
    \fancyhead[LE,LO]{MIPSR1000}
    \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{~\thepage~}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{全文目录}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{MIPSR1000}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{~\thepage~}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centerline{全文目录}}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{全文目录}
\clearpage





\normalsize
\linespread{1.5}\selectfont
%正文，小四号，中文宋体，英文Time new roman，1.5倍行距
\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RE,RO]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[LE,LO]{MIPSR1000}
    \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{~\thepage~}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{MIPSR1000}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{~\thepage~}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


%\chapter{背景}
\section{背景}
\subsection{MIPS R10000 简介}
Mips R10000 是实现Mips IV 指令系统架构的64位动态超标量的微处理器。主要是为了高性能而设计的。它使用了两级的非阻塞的组相联，写回策略的缓存来隐藏内存延迟，即便是在大规模，有很小的内存位置的机器上依然能够保持高性能。它每周期能够取码和译码四条指令。通过分支预测可以在分支结果出来之前推测获取并执行指令，从而尽早地计算内存地址并初始化高速缓存。指令的执行是乱序的，但是指令的提交是按序的。处理器提供了顺序一致性内存模型和精确地中断处理。顺序一致性指的是：（并发程序在多处理器上的）任何一次执行结果和所有处理器的操作按照某个顺序执行，各个微处理器的操作按照其程序指定的顺序进行的结果一样。 精确地异常指的是可以是流水线可以停住的异常，在异常之前的指令能够正常的完成，在异常之后的指令能够被刷新和重新发射。

内存带宽和延迟限制了很多程序的性能。 R1000主要是通过寄存器映射和非阻塞缓存来缓解这些。 当一条指令的操作数没有在缓存中命中，它必须等待操作数加载到缓存中，但是其他的指令能够继续乱序地执行。这有效的增加了内存的使用，并且降低了内存的延迟，因为加载缓存可以更早的开始，当处理器执行其它的指令的时候，最多有四个进程能够并行的填充缓存。非阻塞的定义是：缓存的填充不会阻塞之后对其他缓存行的访问。并且对乱序的处理器添加非阻塞缓存是比较容易的，因此乱序的处理器已经包含处理指令依赖的机制。

R10000的依赖编译器的支持来优化指令的序列。对于数组类型的数据，它是非常有效的，但是对于离散的数据并不是足够的有效，因为编译器很难预测哪一条指令会产生缓存失效。并且R10000的设计中包含动态重排序可用指令的硬件。每当出现缓存失效，指令需要延迟的时候，这个硬件就会起作用，使得处理器最多向前查看32条指令来寻找可能的并行执行的指令。这个指令窗口足够大，能够隐藏大部分从二级缓存加载的延迟。但是只能隐藏少部分从主存加载的延迟，因为访问主存的延迟是很大的。

并且MIPS R10000可以作为单核和多核的系统来使用。它使用了窥探和基于目录的协议来维持缓存的一致性协议。 并且R10000的二级缓存的大小从512K到16M不等。

%MIPS R10000的主要特性包括：
%\begin{itemize}
%   \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
%   \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
%   \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
%   \item 
%   处理器是四路的超标量RISC处理：
%   \begin{itemize}
%       \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
%       \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
%       \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
%       \item 
%       每周期取和译码四条指令
%       \item 
%       利用分支预测进行推测性地执行。
%       \item 
%       动态乱序地执行，按序完成，使用映射表来实现寄存器重命名，并且支持精确中断
%   \end{itemize}
%   \item 
%   处理器是四路的超标量RISC处理：
%   \begin{itemize}
%       \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
%       \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
%       \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
%       \item 
%       每周期取和译码四条指令
%       \item 
%       利用分支预测进行推测性地执行。
%       \item 
%       动态乱序地执行，按序完成，使用映射表来实现寄存器重命名，并且支持精确中断
%   \end{itemize}
%   \item 
%   处理器是四路的超标量RISC处理：
%   \begin{itemize}
%       \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
%       \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
%       \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
%       \item 
%       每周期取和译码四条指令
%       \item 
%       利用分支预测进行推测性地执行。
%       \item 
%       动态乱序地执行，按序完成，使用映射表来实现寄存器重命名，并且支持精确中断
%   \end{itemize}
%   \item 
%   五条独立的流水线执行单元
%       \begin{itemize}
%           \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
%           \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
%           \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
%           \item 
%           每周期取和译码四条指令
%           \item 
%           利用分支预测进行推测性地执行。
%           \item 
%           动态乱序地执行，使用映射表来实现寄存器重命名，并且为了精确中断而实现了按序完成
%       \end{itemize}
%\end{itemize}



%\section{MIPS R10000 实现}
\subsection{R10000 实现}
MIPS R10000是由 MIPS 科技有限公司设计，由NEC以及日本东芝公司以0.35$m\mu$ 的工艺制造在$16.65×17.935-mm$的芯片上，由680万晶体管组成，其中大约440万个是包含在主缓存中. R10000在 1996 年 1 月开始发行, 是为了克制性能限制（存储带宽和时延）而设计的。MIPS R10000 不仅在SPEC指标上取得了惊人的表现，其所使用的无序动态执行调度结构打破了微处理器水平提高的瓶颈，并且其在诸如事务处理，数据采集，决策支持，高档文件及数据服务等实际应用中，达到了当时的最高性能。MIPS R10000 是微处理发展过程中当之无愧的里程碑，为处理器的设计树立了一个新的样板. 


\section{MIPS R10000 指令流水线}



\subsection{二级段落名称}
\subsubsection{三级段落名称}
引用如\upcite{PhysRev.47.777}，引用表如表\ref{tab:input_output_r}，引用图如图\ref{fig:sample}．

\begin{table}[h]
\small %内容，（五号，宋体/Time new roman）
\centering
\caption{不同频率下的输入和输出阻抗}
\label{tab:input_output_r}
\begin{tabular}{cccc} %表格使用三线表
\toprule %不确定说明中三条线的粗细，待改
频率(Hz) & 1 & 10k & 1M \\
\midrule
输入电阻($\Omega/^\circ$) & 339.719k/-87.84 & 5.6707k/-9.827 & 351.188/-72.377\\
输出电阻($\Omega/^\circ$) & 338.638k/-89.663 & 1.9866k/-1.1228 & 1.9189k/-14.801 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=12cm]{Sample.jpg}
\caption{示例图片}
\label{fig:sample}
\end{figure}
\clearpage





\small
\linespread{1}\selectfont
%正文，五号，中文宋体，英文Time new roman，1倍行距
\chapter*{参考文献}
\noindent
\begin{enumerate}[{[1]}]
\small
    \item 期刊
    \item 网络文档
\end{enumerate}

1.  期刊  作者. 论文名. 刊名, 出版年份, 卷号(期号): 起始-截止页

2.  专著  作者. 书名. 版本(第一版不写). 出版城市: 出版社, 出版年份: 起始-截止页

3.  论文集  论文作者. 论文题目//编者. 论文集名: 其他题名信息. 出版城市(或者会议城市): 出版者, 出版年: 引文起始-截止页码

4.  学位论文  作者. 学位论文题名. 城市: 论文保存单位, 年份

5.  网络文献  作者. 题名[文献类型标志/文献载体标志]. 出版地: 出版者, 出版年(更新日期)[引用日期]. 获取和访问路径

*注意: 作者姓前名后, 超过3名作者列前3名, 后加“, 等”; 英文姓名, 姓前名后, 姓首字母大写, 名缩写; 文献的项目要完整, 各项的顺序和标点要和格式要求一致; 未公开发表的论文、报告不列入正式文献, 如有必要可在正文当页下加注。英文文献格式同上。参考文献在正文中按出现顺序用[1], [2]......在右上角标注, 放在“参考文献”中时, 用[1], [2], ...顺序标注。



\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{参考文献}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RE,RO]{参考文献}
    \fancyhead[LE,LO]{MIPSR1000}
    \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{~\thepage~}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{参考文献}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{MIPSR1000}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{~\thepage~}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}






\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{ref}
这是参考“参考文献”，主要用来看引用的顺序，请手动些参考文献或自行写程序，最终编译请删除
\clearpage





% \linespread{1}\selectfont
% \normalsize
% %小四号，中文宋体，英文Time new roman，1倍行距
% \chapter*{本科期间的主要工作和成果}

% \noindent 本科期间参加的主要科研项目

% \noindent 本研基金
% \begin{enumerate}
%   \item 基金名称. 基金类型. 指导老师. 基金支持年限
% \end{enumerate}

% \noindent 各种科研项目
% \begin{enumerate}
%   \item 项目名称. 项目类型
% \end{enumerate}

% 格式下

% 期刊：

% 全部作者. 论文名. 期刊名, 出版年份, 卷号(期号): 起始-截止页

% 会议论文：

% 全部作者. 论文名. 会议名, 会议举办地, 会议举办时间, 起始-截止页

% 专利

% 全部专利申请人. 专利名称. 专利申请号. 专利申请日期. 国别



\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{本科期间的主要工作和成果}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RE,RO]{本科期间的主要工作和成果}
    \fancyhead[LE,LO]{MIPSR1000}
    \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{~\thepage~}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{本科期间的主要工作和成果}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{MIPSR1000}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{~\thepage~}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\clearpage





% \linespread{1.5}\selectfont
% \normalsize
% %正文，小四号，中文宋体，英文Time new roman，1.5倍行距
% \chapter*{致谢}



% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{致谢}
% \fancypagestyle{plain}
% {
%   \fancyhf{}
%   \fancyhead[RE,RO]{致谢}
%   \fancyhead[LE,LO]{MIPSR1000}
%   \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{~\thepage~}
%   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
%   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
% }
% \fancyhf{}
% \fancyhead[RE,RO]{致谢}
% \fancyhead[LE,LO]{MIPSR1000}
% \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{~\thepage~}
% \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}
% \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}





\end{document}
```